# [VS 2015][C++11][Armadillo] Linspace Initialization

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015, armadillo

hope you can give me some advice on the following. As per title, my current setup is VS2015, C++11, Armadillo.

I have got the class

```
class MyClass
{

public:
    MyClass();
    virtual ~MyClass();
    arma::vec myVec;
    void MakeVec(int sz);
};
```

where:

```
void MyClass::MakeVec(int sz)
{
    myVec = arma::linspace(0.0, 1.0, sz);
}
```

As far as I can tell this is causing a memory leak detected by the ARMA debug when running the program, i.e. "Debug Assertion Failed - _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)".

In the [official](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#linspace) documentation page they do it only when declaring the variable, but in my case I'd like to make a linspace at runtime. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's not a memory leak, it seems like heap corruption. Are you sure you are using debug DLLs in debug mode and release DLLs in release mode?

Comment: I'm currently in debug mode. How do I verify which DLLs I'm using? Also, my projects are configured to be built as static lib (.lib) rather than DLLs. Can it be an issue?

Comment: I've tried to play around with .dll and .lib but at the end it didn't help!

Comment: What I mean is, when you build Armadillo make sure you build both Debug and Release DLLs and then in your main project properties make sure you link against the correct ones. If you're using precompiled binaries, make sure they match your compiler version and mode (debug/release).